# perl6 Performance difference between @$aList and $aList

Tags: arrays, performance, list, raku

I have data structures that are very large and need to be assigned and passed around. I also need to get inside the list. Sometimes when a list is in a scalar container, `$aList.elems` will say `1` because there is only one element which is the list. To get inside the list, `(@$aList).elems` will give the correct number of elements in the list.

My question is: is there a performance disadvantage with using `@$aList` frequently, and if there is a performance issue, will assigning `@b = @$aList` and use `@b` instead solve the issue? I.e., will there be speed bump with switching from list to array context?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you smls ! There are a number of cases where @$xyz works and $xyz does not. I can't think of an example right now. Let me dig up my files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$x.elems` and `(@$x).elems` should return the same number.
So it sounds like there's a bug in your code that you should fix... Possibly something related to `Seq` caching, see below.

As for the performance question, I haven't run benchmarks, but note that `@$x` simply calls `$x.cache`, which...

- if `$x` is a `List` or subclass (which includes `Array`), simply returns the object itself (without the surrounding item container), which should be fast.
- if `$x` is an object of another type, creates a new `List` from it and returns that, which will likely have a bit more overhead depending on the type. e.g.:

  - **String** `"a"` --> **List** `("a",)`
  - **Range** `1..10` --> **List** `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`
    Obviously, for huge Ranges, coercing to a list will have a significant memory and CPU performance cost.
  - **Seq** `(1, 2).Seq` --> **List** `(1, 2)`
    The Seq case is special, because it remembers the `List` object that's created the first time `.cache` is called on it, and continues to return the same one on subsequent calls. That's why the method is called `.cache` in the first place.

(Note that the `.list` method also exists, which does the same thing as `.cache` except that it doesn't remember the List in the `Seq` case.)

Comment: Thank you smls for the clarification. @$x and $x are not exactly the same:

> my @a=(1,2,3);
[1 2 3]
> my %h
{}
> push %h<x>, @a
[[1 2 3]]
> push %h<x>, @a
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3]]
> push %h<x>, @a
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]]
> for %h -> $b { say $b; for @($b.value) -> $c {say $c;} }
x => [[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3] #on 3 lines
> for %h -> $b { say $b; for ($b.value) -> $c {say $c;} }
x => [[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]]
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]] #1 item, 1 line

Seems iterable in a scalar container is counted as one element, but @($xyz) reaches inside the iterable.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of my last comment. ">" is the prompt from perl6 interpreter.

Comment: for %h -> $b { say $b; for @($b.value) -> $c {say $c;} } is different from for %h -> $b { say $b; for ($b.value) -> $c {say $c;} } ; sorry it is hard to see because the limitations on the formatting in comments.

Comment: Ok, here I composed a simple examaple: my $b = (1,2,3,4,5); for $b -> $c { say $c; }; for @$b -> $c { say $c; }; the first "for" loop gives you one item on one line, "(1 2 3 4 5)", but the second "for" loop gives you 5 items on 5 lines, from 1 to 5. Thanks.

Comment: @lisprogtor: Ah, but that's not `.elems` (or another method call) - that would act the same regardless of whether the invocant is in an item container or not. What you're seeing there, is the `for` loop specifically checking whether the object given in its loop header is wrapped in an item container, and if so, treating it as a single item.